# .eslintrc error Parsing error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: vuejs3, vite, eslintrc

I am using vite, eslint, and vue3 typescript. When I run command:

```
npm run lint
```

I get numerous errors:

```
0:0  error  Parsing error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

My .eslintrc.js setup is:

```
module.exports = {
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
    'prettier'
  ],
  rules: {
    // override/add rules settings here, such as:
    // 'vue/no-unused-vars': 'error'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This fixed the problem, .eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: "vue-eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
      parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      sourceType: "module"
  },
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
    'prettier'
  ],
  rules: {
    // override/add rules settings here, such as:
    // 'vue/no-unused-vars': 'error'
  }
}
```